# Как сделать CRC криптографическим?

Tags: криптография, crc

тема моей дипломной работы "Криптографические алгоритмы CRC". Я прочитал много информации про CRC, подскажите как сделать CRC криптографическим.

Comment: Если CRC станет криптографическим, он будет уже не CRC. Видимо у вас какое то очень широкое понятие CRC ...

Comment: Другими словами это называется электронная подпись. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Электронная_подпись